# TypeScript: imported module classes are not visible

Tags: typescript

I am testing the typescript compiler with multiple modules that would be compiled as AMD modules.

I have a module "test" and a separate file that will use it

test.ts:

```
export module test {
'use strict';

  export class Person {
      age:number = 0;
      sin:number = 1;
  }

  var pp = new Person();

}
```

test.ts declares module "test" and exports it.
the file compiles and js out put is as expected:

test.js:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
(function (test) {
    'use strict';
    var Person = (function () {
        function Person() {
            this.age = 0;
            this.sin = 1;
        }
        return Person;
    })();
    test.Person = Person;        
    var pp = new Person();
})(exports.test || (exports.test = {}));
var test = exports.test;
})
```

Now in the same folder there is test2.ts that would be using module "test"

test2.ts:

```
///<reference path="test.ts"/>

import TT = module("test");

var p = TT.Person;
```

the compiler complains here:

> src/ts/test2.ts(5,11): The property 'Person' does not exist on value of type 'TT'

The output js file seems to be correct though:
test2.js:

```
define(["require", "exports", "test"], function(require, exports, __TT__) {
  ///<reference path="test.ts"/>
  var TT = __TT__;

  var p = TT.Person;
})
```

the compiler version is:

> 0.8.2.0

command line is:

> tsc --comments --declaration --target ES5 --module AMD $FilePath$

What is the problem with compiler here?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you need...

```
import TT = module("test");

var p = new TT.test.Person();
```

And a quick explanation.

When you are using AMD or CommonJS to load your modules and you are using `import` statements, you don't need to use `reference` comments. The `import` does everything you need.

Also, the file itself is the module, so `TT` in your code represents `test.ts`. Inside of this file (which is a module) is another module explicitly called `test`, so in fact you have a structure like this: `test.test.Person`.

You could opt to just use the file module and not add another nested one, like this:

*test.ts*

```
export class Person {
    age:number = 0;
    sin:number = 1;
}

var pp = new Person();
```

This would allow you to use the non-nested version, which is:

```
import TT = module("test");

var p = new TT.Person();
```

Comment: "the file itself is the module, so TT in your code represents test.ts."  
    
That was the key point.  It works now. Thanks.   I will follow your suggestion and remove the "in file module" until I see an actual need for it.

Comment: do you put the "import" statement inside a "class" statement or outside? (I want to import a module into another class)