# TypeScript - Module is undefined at runtime

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I dont understand what i'm doing wrong. I've create a TypeScript project in VS2012, and created a file named "Vector.ts", in a sub-directory named "Physics":

```
// Module
module Physics {

    // Class
    export class Vector {
        constructor(public x: number) { }
    }

}
```

Also, I have the following app.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="Physics/Vector.ts" />

window.onload = () => {
    var vector = new Physics.Vector(6);
};
```

The project is successfully compiled, but when i launch it, i get the following exception:

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Physics' is undefined

I don't understand what am i doing wrong...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using AMD style modules with a module loader such as Require.Js, you need an import statement. See Steve's accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919495/1014822  Your code will look something like:

```
import Physics = module("Physics/Vector");

var vector = new Physics.Vector(6);
```

... and you won't need this: `/// <reference path="Physics/Vector.ts" />`

If you are not using a module loader, you just need to make sure you include your `Vector.js` output file somewhere in your html page, and make sure it loads before your app file. In this case, you use `/// <reference path="Physics/Vector.ts" />` to tell TS where to find your module for intellisense etc. to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I make sure that my Vector.js file loads before the app.js?

Comment: Just found a nice tutorial about it - http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, if you're using `System` then you'd use the `import` `function`:

```
System.import("Physics/Vector");
```

If you're doing this for `Angular 2` then you'd want to do this before your `bootstrap` `import`